# How do I check if a stored procedure is defined in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When I do :

```
select routine_definition
from information_schema.routines
where routine_name = 'sp_name';
```

it returns a row, but the routine_definition column is `NULL`.  Does this mean that this Stored Procedure is not defined?

Also, when I do `show create procedure sp_name`, it says that procedure does not exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run these other queries

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE name='sp_name';
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE name='sp_name';
SELECT type,db,body FROM mysql.proc WHERE name='sp_name'\G
```

If the procedure does not show up from any of these queries, my condolences.

There is one hope left: If you have a physical backup of the `mysql.proc`, do this in a Staging DB:

- `service mysql stop`
- Copy the backup of `/var/lib/mysql` into the Staging DB
- `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`
- `service mysql start`

Once you do that, you can mysqldump all the stored procedures out of it with

```
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="-uroot -p..."
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --routines"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --no-data"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --no-create-info"
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > MySQLStoredProcs.sql
```

Now, go `vi` or `nano` the file and get the Stored Procedure out of it.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-02-05 11:58 EDT

If you are really having problems with visually seeing the Stored Procedure's code, you may have a corrupt `proc.MYD` file. Try retrieving from backup as I already mentioned.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for remembering my signature !!!

Comment: It had to be done :)

Comment: SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE name='sp_name' returns a row. So, how do I view the query it's executing if show create procedure sp_name says the the procedure doesn't exit and the routine_definition column is null in information_schema.routines

Comment: Please paste the output of `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE name='sp_name'` into your question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA it says query executed successfully but it does not return any result.

Comment: Please paste the output of `SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE name='sp_name'\G` into your question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA : I get a permission denied error.  I am working on resolving that.  BTW, do you think I should create a new post at this point?

Comment: Are you using shared hosting or a dedicated server with full OS access ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA : It was a permissions issue.  I could see as soon as I logged in using different credentials.  What I don't understand why I could see some stored procedures and not others.

Comment: You should run `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` when you connect. You'll see what permissions you have. From that, you could deduce what missing privileges you need (maybe CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, or EXECUTE).